# Can't send mail with attachment

Tags: java, blackberry, sendmail

I write code for sending mail with attachment from my BlackBerry device to my gmail account.

The mail is sent without an error. But the problem is the attachment part is not working. The message simply doesn't contain my attachment!

Please help me to solve the issue.

Multipart mp = new Multipart(); 
            byte[] data = readFile(strFileName);
            String fileData = "just a simple test";
            String messageData = msgField.getText();
            SupportedAttachmentPart sap= null;

```
        try{
            sap = new SupportedAttachmentPart(mp,"application/x-example",strFileName, data);
        }catch (Exception e) {
            Dialog.inform(e.toString());
        }
        TextBodyPart tbp = new TextBodyPart(mp,messageData); 

        mp.addBodyPart(tbp); 
        mp.addBodyPart(sap); 

        Folder[] folders = Session.getDefaultInstance().getStore().list(Folder.SENT); 

        Message message = new Message(folders[0]); 

        try{ 
            Address toAdd = new Address(toField.getText(), toField.getText()); 
            Address[] toAdds = new Address[1]; 
            toAdds[0] = toAdd; 
            message.addRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,toAdds);
            message.setSubject(subjectField.getText());
            message.setContent(mp); 
            Transport.send(message); 
        }catch (Exception e){ 
            Dialog.inform(e.toString()); 
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's a complete code for send email with attachments. You can send multiple attachments a single message, just add all parts to Multipart.

```
 try {
        // create a multipart
        StringBuffer sbFileBody = new StringBuffer();
        Multipart mp = new Multipart();
        TextBodyPart tbp = new TextBodyPart(mp, "your message body");
        SupportedAttachmentPart sap = new SupportedAttachmentPart(mp, "text/plain", "info.txt", sbFileBody.toString().getBytes("UTF-8"));
        mp.addBodyPart(tbp);
        mp.addBodyPart(sap);

        ServiceConfiguration sc = null;
        ServiceRecord[] records = ServiceBook.getSB().getRecords();
        for (int i = 0; i < records.length; i++) {
            if (records[i].getCid().equalsIgnoreCase("CMIME") && !records[i].isDisabled() && records[i].isValid()) {
                ServiceConfiguration sct = new ServiceConfiguration(records[i]);
                String mailAddress = sct.getEmailAddress().toLowerCase();
                if (mailAddress.equals("from@address.com")) {
                    //use sc;
                    sc = sct;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        if (sc != null) {

            Session session = Session.getInstance(sc);
            Store store = session.getStore();
            Folder[] folders = store.list(Folder.SENT);
            Folder sentfolder = folders[0];

            if (sentfolder != null) {
                Message message = new Message(sentfolder);
                Address toAdress = new Address("to@address.com", "to address");
                message.setFrom(new Address(sc.getEmailAddress(), sc.getName()));
                message.addRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, new Address[] { toAdress });
                message.setSubject("Your mail subject");
                message.setContent(mp);
                message.addMessageListener(new MessageListener() {
                    public void changed(MessageEvent e) {
                        if (e.getMessage().getStatus() == Message.Status.TX_SENT) {
                            try {
                                e.getMessage().removeMessageListener(this);
                                System.out.println("Send complete");
                            } catch (Exception ex) {
                                ex.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
                Transport.send(message);

            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: @yOrk: thanks york..is there any other configuration needed for this to work..i tried the code , but its not working..is it neccessary for me to run the ess simulator for the working of this application..

Comment: @Tijo, i'm already use code on real devices. just compile , sign and run on real device. you must set **from@address.com** to valid mail address(it must be installed on device).

Comment: @yOrk: thanks york..its working with your test code..no problem with your code..but here in your code you are hardcoded the file name and the content type..but i want the user to pick his own file using a filepicker and attach that with the message..when am doing like this way, i am getting the error that i mentioned.. means the message is going without an error..but there is no attachment.my code is something like in the below comment..

Answer (score 1):

you can follow this link also:
[j2me/BlackBerry - How to send Email with Attachment from Application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2599619/j2me-blackberry-how-to-send-email-with-attachment-from-application)

i also got this issue while i was sending attachment
i made a mistake here:  msg.setContent(multipart);

so please check the code and compare with other codes as given by y0rk or as specified in the link