# Can i generate PDF reports in Blackberry?

Tags: blackberry, pdf-generation, blackberry-eclipse-plugin

Can i generate a report in PDF and send across mail ?

What API i have to use for this and what are the licence available ? are their any opensource or freeware apis ?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no built in API's for generating PDF file in blackberry. But based on this [discussion,](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Tablet-OS-SDK-for-Adobe-AIR/Generating-PDF-Based-on-Input/td-p/1074919) you can achieve by using some third party API's.

Look at this discussion for [send a email with attachment.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2599619/j2me-blackberry-how-to-send-email-with-attachment-from-application)